# Is it possible to send the output of -w and -o Curl streams to different files? How?

Tags: curl, stdout, stderr

I'd like to run a curl command, 
grep the output (response payload) for some keywords, 
then also print some metrics via the -w option.

I think this would be easy to do if I could direct the -o output into a stream that is distinct from the -w output (which is always stdout).

tee sends the output of BOTH -w and -o (that is to say, stdout) to multiple places. I want the output of -w to go to one stream, and the output of -o to go to another stream.

How?

Comment: can you not do this using `tee`? can you post a sample of the curl command you want to run?

Answer (score 1):

Try `tee`. From the manpage:

> `# source_program | tee (> program1) (> program2) (> programN)| programN+1`

Comment: tee sends the output of BOTH -w and -o to multiple places. I want the output of -w to go to one stream, and the output of -o to go to another.